# Which schema.xml file edit in Solr?

Tags: solr, schema

I downloaded a Solr package from here: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/mirrors-solr-latest-redir.html

I want to create a new field in *schema.xml* file, but I don't know in which one - in downloaded folder there are 7 *schema.xml* files.

I edited all of this files, but nothing changed.

Where should I add a new field definition?

Comment: Are you running in cloud mode..? If so you will have to upload the updated schema.xml to ZooKeeper. May be you know already, you will have to reload the core to make the new schema.xml to be effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have standard distribution (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/mirrors-solr-latest-redir.html) you can find your cores at solr-5.2.1/server/solr

One problem you might face is that you don't have any cores defined yet. If that is a case copy solr-5.2.1\server\solr\configsets\basic_configs to solr-5.2.1\server\solr\my_new_core (rename folder) - congratz, you defined a new core.

Now run the server: run in command line solr-5.2.1\bin\solr with parameter start. Open in your browser: http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~cores/example_core and Add core with instanceDir = my_new_core. This initializes your core - makes it fully functional.

Now you can find solr-5.2.1\server\solr\example_core\conf\solrconfig.xml
and configure it as you will. After changing solrconfig.xml remember to reload core at Core Admin.

Answer (score 1):

Create a solr instance by running a command from the command prompt
 `solr create -c test` 
Here test is the collection name.Copy schema.xml and solrconfig.xml from techproducts project folder to conf folder of the test project.Now you can define your schema in the schema.xml.